# Dotnetopenauth with webservice backend instead of database

Tags: web-services, dotnetopenauth, membership-provider

I'm planning to add OpenAuth authentication to an existing asp.net webforms application with a custom membership provider. That is not a problem of what I have seen on the net (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/12/integrate-openauth-openid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers.aspx), but I do not have access to a local database for the two extra tables of data that OpenAuth want to add. All data must be fetched using web services. Is there any easy way to override the implementation of OpenAuth's database access to use web services instead? Perhaps someone has done this already or has any ideas of how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any clue on how to override the database communication to use web services, so I made a new custom class that mimics the class Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth. The methods that I wrote was Login, AddAccountToExistingUser, CreateUser, GetAccountsForUser and DeleteAccount. All of these makes appropriate calls to my web service that stores the data in my custom database schema. The Login method also calls FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie.

The rest of Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth can be used as far as I can tell now. I guess that all methods called *LocalPassword* also should be implemented, but I haven't done it yet.

This is most probably not the best solution, but it worked for me and I can now use Google, etc to authenticate users.